# Using PowerShell to call the GraphAPI and create a folder in a SharePoint document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

So I am trying to create a new folder in a SharePoint library using Graph API. I can get the access token just fine, but whenever I send a request to create a new folder, I get (400) bad request. Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
#header containing access token
$header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer " + $resp.access_token
}

$CreateFolderURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/(Here I write the drive ID)/items/root/children"

$uploadFolderRequestBody = @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder = $null
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"= "rename"
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method Post -Body $uploadFolderRequestBody -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $CreateFolderURL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `folder = @{}` instead of `folder = $null`.

It produces a json where `"folder" : null` but it should be `"folder" : {}`

```
$uploadFolderRequestBody = @{
name= "NewFolder"
folder = @{}
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"= "rename"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

It will produce the expected json

```
{
    "name":  "NewFolder",
    "folder":  {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":  "rename"
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something small, that worked, thanks so much